# Difference of (sqrt-iter-cond 1 x) and (sqrt-iter-cond 1.0 x)

Tags: elisp, sicp

I read the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58899297/7301792 which find the sqrt with iteration

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :session sicp :lexical t
(defun sqrt-iter-cond(guess x)
  (cond ((good-enough-p guess x) guess)
        (t (sqrt-iter-cond (improve guess x) x))
   )
  )
(defun good-enough-p(guess x)
  (< (abs (- (square guess) x)) 0.001))

(defun improve(guess x)
  (average guess (/ x guess)))

(defun average(x y)
  (/ (+ x y) 2))

(sqrt-iter-cond 1.0 13))

#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 3.6055513629176015
```

However, if change 1.0 to 1, it report error

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :session sicp :lexical t
(sqrt-iter-cond 1 13)

#+end_src
Lisp nesting exceeds ‘max-lisp-eval-depth’
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: Hint: `(setq debug-on-error t)`

Answer (score 2):

Consider the difference between calling your `average` function with two integers and calling it with two numbers where one or more is a floating-point number:

```
(average 3 4)
3
```

vs.

```
(average 3.0 4)
3.5
```

With integers, you get stuck in an infinite loop because `improve` calls `average`, which eventually keeps returning the same integer value due to integer arithmetic. But with floating-point numbers, `improve` actually moves the guess closer to the result on each call because `average` isn't limited to returning only integers.

An easy fix for the problem is to change the `average` function to divide by 2.0 instead of 2:

```
(defun average(x y)
  (/ (+ x y) 2.0))
```

If you set `debug-on-error` to `t`, the backtrace with the original code gives you an idea of where the problem is:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Lisp nesting exceeds ‘max-lisp-eval-depth’")
  (abs (- (* guess guess) x))
  (< (abs (- (* guess guess) x)) 0.001)
  good-enough-p(3 13)
  (cond ((good-enough-p guess x) guess) (t (sqrt-iter-cond (improve guess x) x)))
  sqrt-iter-cond(3 13)
  (cond ((good-enough-p guess x) guess) (t (sqrt-iter-cond (improve guess x) x)))
  sqrt-iter-cond(3 13)
  (cond ((good-enough-p guess x) guess) (t (sqrt-iter-cond (improve guess x) x)))
  sqrt-iter-cond(3 13)
  ...
```

The `...` is there to indicate that the backtrace just keeps repeating.

Alternatively, just adding a `message` call into the `improve` function can help:

```
(defun improve(guess x)
  (message (format "guess: %f, x: %f" guess x))
  (average guess (/ x guess)))
```

With the original `average` function using integer arithmetic, the `*Message*` buffer shows:

```
guess: 4.000000, x: 13.000000
guess: 3.000000, x: 13.000000 [391 times]
```

With floating-point numbers, the messages show the guess converging to the answer:

```
guess: 1.000000, x: 13.000000
guess: 7.000000, x: 13.000000
guess: 4.428571, x: 13.000000
guess: 3.682028, x: 13.000000
guess: 3.606345, x: 13.000000
```